# How to select a specific mailbox from IMAP server?

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I have the following mailboxes on my IMAP server (refer to the attached screenshot).[image]

I want to only select the mailbox Folder1 and check if there are any sub-directories. I already tried the following code:

```
svr = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_address)
svr.login(user, pwd)
svr.select('inbox') <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
rv, data = svr.search(None, "ALL")
test, folders = svr.list('""', '*')
print(folders)
```

I thought changing 'inbox' to 'folder1' (statement indicated with arrows) would select Folder1 and then I can retrieve the sub-directories. But nothing happened and still it shows the same result as 'inbox'.

Can somebody help me understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: LIST does not operate on the currently selected mailbox, it is a global command.  Have you tried changing the parameters of list()?

Comment: @Max I worked on it and was able to get the desired result. I'll post my code as solution. Please check if anything else needs to be modified or the process can be made faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I would not be knowing the name of folder I tried a different approach. I would first collect all the folders in the root directory and then parse them one by one to check if any sub-directory exists.

```
root_folders = []
svr = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_address)
svr.login(user, pwd)
svr.select('inbox')
response, folders = svr.list('""', '*')

def parse_mailbox(data):
    flags, b, c = data.partition(' ')
    separator, b, name = c.partition(' ')
    return flags, separator.replace('"', ''), name.replace('"', '')

def subdirectory(folder):
    #For directories 'Deleted Items', 'Sent Items', etc. with whitespaces,
    #the name of the directory needs to be passed with double quotes, hence '"' + name + '"'
    test, folders = obj.list('""','"' + name+ '/*"')
    if(folders is not None):
        print('Subdirectory exists') # you can also call parse_mailbox to find the name of sub-directory

for mbox in folders:
    flags, separator, name = parse_mailbox(bytes.decode(mbox))
    fmt = '{0}    : [Flags = {1}; Separator = {2}'
    if len(name.split('/')) > 1:
        continue
    else:
        root_folders.append(name)

for folder in root_folders:
    subdirectory(folder)
```

Although this is a tailored code from my script, but this should be the solution for the question put up.